# written code for Autofit in c# for Excel sheet. Everything is perfect. but the Excel.exe is still running even after clearing com componets

Tags: c#, excel

This is my code. I am trying to export gridview to excel with some of the cells with color and autofit. The problem here is everything is working fine except the EXCEL.EXE running in the background. But If i exclude code for Autofit and coloring cells, then the Excel Task is terminated.

Below is my code

```
    protected void xlsWorkBook()
    {
        try
        {
            Excel.Application oXL;
            Excel.Workbook oWB;
            Excel.Workbooks oWBs;
            Excel.Worksheet oSheet;
            Excel.Range oRange;
            // Start Excel and get Application object.
            oXL = new Excel.Application();
            // Set some properties
            oXL.Visible = false;
            oXL.DisplayAlerts = false;
            // Get a new workbook.
            oWBs = oXL.Workbooks;
            oWB = oWBs.Add(1);
            oSheet = oWB.ActiveSheet;

            DataGridView dataGridExport = new DataGridView();
            dataGridExport.DataSource = GetData();
            bool isColorCells = false;

            oRange = oSheet.Cells;
            for (int k = 1; k <= dataGridExport.Columns.Count; k++)
            {
                //oRange.set_Item(1, k, dataGridExport.Columns[k - 1].Name); 
                oSheet.Cells[1, k] = dataGridExport.Columns[k - 1].Name;
                ((dynamic)oSheet.Cells[1, k]).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.SteelBlue);
            }
            for (int i = 1; i <= dataGridExport.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int k = 1; k <= dataGridExport.Rows[i - 1].Cells.Count; k++)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToString(dataGridExport.Rows[i - 1].Cells[k - 1].Value) != string.Empty)
                    {
                        //oRange.set_Item(i + 1, k, dataGridExport.Rows[i - 1].Cells[k - 1].Value);
                        oSheet.Cells[i + 1, k] = dataGridExport.Rows[i - 1].Cells[k - 1].Value;

                    }
                    if ((isColorCells) && (dataGridExport.Rows[i - 1].Cells[k - 1].Style.BackColor.ToArgb() != 0))
                    {
                        //oRange.Interior.Color = Color.Red;
                        ((dynamic)oSheet.Cells[i + 1, k]).Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.FromArgb(dataGridExport.Rows[i - 1].Cells[k - 1].Style.BackColor.ToArgb()));
                    }
                }
            }
            dataGridExport = null;
            oSheet.Columns.AutoFit();
            //oRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
            // Save the sheet and close
            //oSheet = null;
            //oRange = null;
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel File|*.xlsx";
            saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save an Excel File";
            saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
            {

                oWB.SaveAs(saveFileDialog1.FileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
                          Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlUserResolution, true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
            }

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            oWB.Close();
            oXL.Quit();

            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oRange);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oSheet);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oWB);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oWBs);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oXL);



            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = ex.Message;
        }
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding Garbage Collection in .net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130382/understanding-garbage-collection-in-net)

Answer (score 0):

Moving Range to different function solved my problem. The Excel.exe is not running at the background anymore. But i am not sure why. Somebody can give explanation for this?

```
       protected void xlsWorkBook()
       {
            Excel.Application oXL;
            Excel.Workbook oWB;
            Excel.Worksheet oSheet;
            // Start Excel and get Application object.
            oXL = new Excel.Application();
            // Set some properties
            //oXL.Visible = false;
            oXL.DisplayAlerts = false;
            // Get a new workbook.
            oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value);

            oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
            UpdataDataToExcelSheets(oSheet,"sheet name",dataGrid1,true);

            // Save the sheet and close
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel File|*.xlsx";
            saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save an Excel File";
            saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
            {

                oWB.SaveAs(saveFileDialog1.FileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
                          Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlUserResolution, true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
            }

            oWB.Close();
            oXL.Quit();
            //// Clean up
            if (oSheet != null)
            {
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oSheet);
                oSheet = null;
            }
            if (oWB != null)
            {
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oWB);
                oWB = null;
            }
            if (oXL.Workbooks != null)
            {
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oXL.Workbooks);
            }
            if (oXL != null)
            {
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oXL);
                oXL = null;
            }
            //// NOTE: When in release mode, this does the trick
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
      }

       private void UpdataDataToExcelSheets(Excel.Worksheet oSheet,string sheetName, DataGridView  dataGridExport,bool isColorCells)
    {
        Excel.Range oRange;
        oSheet.Name = sheetName;
        for (int k = 1; k <= dataGridExport.Columns.Count; k++)
        {
            oSheet.Cells[1, k] = dataGridExport.Columns[k - 1].Name;
            ((dynamic)oSheet.Cells[1, k]).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.SteelBlue);
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= dataGridExport.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 1; k <= dataGridExport.Rows[i - 1].Cells.Count; k++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToString(dataGridExport.Rows[i - 1].Cells[k - 1].Value) != string.Empty)
                {
                    oSheet.Cells[i + 1, k] = dataGridExport.Rows[i - 1].Cells[k - 1].Value;
                }
                if ((isColorCells)&&(dataGridExport.Rows[i - 1].Cells[k - 1].Style.BackColor.ToArgb() != 0))
                {
                    ((dynamic)oSheet.Cells[i + 1, k]).Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.FromArgb(dataGridExport.Rows[i - 1].Cells[k - 1].Style.BackColor.ToArgb()));
                }
            }
        }
        oRange = oSheet.Range[oSheet.Cells[1, 1],
        oSheet.Cells[dataGridExport.Rows.Count - 1, dataGridExport.Columns.Count + 1]];
        oRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit();

        if (oRange != null)
        {
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oRange);
            oRange = null;
        }
    }
```